# extend python list with a specified number

Tags: python

Is there a way to extend the list by a specified number? Initially I have a list of size 5 and depending on the return value of some function, I need to extend the list by that size. This is my code

```
list = [0,0] # size is 2

size = some_function()  # function returns 3

list.extend(size)

print len(list)   # should print 5
```

Comment: Why exactly you would like to do that?

Comment: Python doesn't allow empty list elements, but you could do e.g. `lst.extend([None] * size)` (don't name your own list `list`).

Comment: Or maybe `[0]*size`, considering that you pre-filled the list with two `0`s`? But the same idea as @jonrsharpe suggested.

Comment: @thefourtheye I am trying to populate the particular list index after extending it. Initially the size is 2. So I cant access the 5th element in the list. Once I extend the size to 5, I can populate the 5th element later in other function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe of course Im not naming my list as "list". Just giving an example here

Comment: @user1085459 You mean, you are inserting values at the list in particular position, in random order?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary with integer keys?

Comment: Presumably you would eventually be putting stuff in the newly created slots.  I advise waiting until you are ready to add items and then just use `my_list.extend(items)` or `for item in whatever:my_list.append(item)`.  If you *really* need to do what you are asking you can do `list.extend([0] * size)`.  (You can replace `0` with whatever object you like.)

Comment: @thefourtheye I am always inserting elements to the list at the end.

Comment: @user1085459 You need to give us some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have a concept of 'pre-allocating' size for lists. Lists are implemented as arraylists and are designed to grow dynamically by fixed size partitions. And an index in a list must always contain a value, there's no such thing as an allocated but empty index (at least that the user has access to).

In most cases, there will be very little performance gain to artificially inflating the size of the list before actually adding elements to it. This is compounded by the fact that lists are lists of references, so you're not even preallocating memory for any particular object, just for a bunch of pointers. If, however, that's really what you want, you could do the following:

```
lst.extend([None]*size)
```

This will grow the list by the given size (note I changed the name of the variable from `list` to `lst` so as not to shadow the builtin `list`), and fill the slots with `None`. However, generally speaking it's much better to just extend when you have the items, or append them as you go.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe

```
my_list  = [0,0]
new_size = 3
#my_list = [my_list[0]] * (new_size + len(my_list))
my_list += [None] * new_size
```

this would be an approach but my_list.extend is far better than my answer

Comment: This would fill every element in the new list with the value of the first element in the original list. Almost certainly *not* what is intended.